# Predator/Prey simulation

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create two simulated robots which will engage in predator/prey behavior.  I don't actually care what kind of robots they are, the simpler the better.  But I do need a way to detect when the predator collides with the prey in order to remove the prey from the simulation (due to being eaten).

I've managed to get a few turtles running in the turtlesim, but how would I go about doing collision detection?  Would I have to roll my own node or is there something existing I can use?

If I switched from turtlesim to either stage or gazebo, would this be easier to leverage pre-built tools do the collision detection?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50676/predator/prey-simulation/) by [tleyden](https://answers.ros.org/users/3760/tleyden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2012-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Turtlesim you'd have to write your own node that would detect collision based on turtle distance. However since your predator/prey code needs a node anyway, you can implement that in that node.

Turtlesim is meant as a toy for learning how to program, but it might be sufficient for your needs.

The advantage of stage and Gazebo are that much more complex robots can be represented, that they have an actual shape, and there can be an environment with walls. however detecting a collision and removing the prey would probably be at least as hard as in turtlesim.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tleyden](https://answers.ros.org/users/3760/tleyden/) on 2012-12-18**:
Thanks!  My plan is to see how far I can get with turtlesim, then switch over to Stage or Gazebo.  (probably Gazebo).  I just asked a more specific question regarding collision detection in gazebo: http://answers.ros.org/question/50715/turtlebot-collision-detection-in-gazebo/